# Web Crawling on Internet Banking

Tags: java, javascript, web-crawler

i'm trying to crawl an Internet banking website to some Internet banking in my country. This crawler can be use to login to internet banking account, clicking menu in the web then load the transaction data in the given period of time.

actually this is my final project research. is anyone have tried to crawl internet banking before?

I've tried jSoup, Selenium and other library in java, the results is a dead end. I've tried HtmlUnit in java desktop too but its kinda stuck in loading javascript page. some of the form and file.js can't be loaded.

It's really helping if anyone can suggest me what library to use or what language to use.
sorry for my bad english. thanx before

Comment: I guarantee that there's a whole team of people in the bank doing their utmost to stop you doing this. Think __big__ security problem.

Comment: @Mike W , only problem that i see hes going to face is that many banks use external code generators to get into internet banking.If he simulate human behavior there is no problem to do this.What kind of security feature coud stop him from doing this in your opinion? (Just interested).In worst case scenario he can use robot class with computer vision library and basicly scan for anything that he needs.(Not really crawling tho)

Comment: If you remember to keep sessions alive and not start new ones for every new call, it should work to emulate human behaviour. However, I would start with something simpler than an online banking site ;)